# An array of objects is returned to me. How to return an array of objects where only the unique groups with the maximum value will remain?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typeorm

```
[
{"score": 99, "group":"1"},
{"score": 90, "group":"2"},
{"score":"10", "group":"1"},
{"score":"10",      "group":"2"},
]
```

I work with TypeOrm now and want to filter data.

Expected array:

```
[
{"score": 99,      "group":"1"},
{"score": 90,     "group":"2"},
]
```

Comment: please add your code. what goes wrong?

Comment: some of your score properties are strings instead of numbers. Was this a typo, or do strings need to be treated as numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const data = [
{"score": 99, "group":"1"},
{"score": 90, "group":"2"},
{"score": 10, "group":"1"},
{"score": 10, "group":"2"}]

const result = [...new Set(data.map(i=>i.group))] // get unique group ids
  .map(g=>data.filter(({group})=>g===group) // find members of each group 
  .sort(({score:a},{score:b})=>a-b).pop()) // find the one with highest score

console.log(result)
```

If your data includes scores that are strings instead of numbers, change `a-b` to `(+a)-(+b)` to coerce the strings to numbers.

Comment: lot of stuff to do ... btw, `-` coerces to number.

Comment: @NinaScholz good point. For some reason I remember there being edge cases in code I've written before where coercion was required, but I'm drawing a blank to remember what those edge cases were now

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#groupBy) in this case

```
function maxGroups() {
let arr = [
    {"score": 99, "group":"1"},
    {"score": 90, "group":"2"},
    {"score": 10, "group":"1"},
    {"score": 10, "group":"2"},
]

let newArr = _.groupBy(arr, "group")
let result = _.map(newArr, i => (_.maxBy(i, 'score')));
console.dir(result)
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You could take a single loop approach with an object for keeping the groups.

```js
const
    data = [{ score: 99, group: "1" }, { score: 90, group: "2" }, { score: 10, group: "1" }, { score: 10, group: "2" }],
    maxScore = Object.values(data.reduce((r, o) => {
        if (!r[o.group] || r[o.group].score < o.score) r[o.group] = o;
        return r;
    }, {}));
    
console.log(maxScore);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply group by `group` keeping only the objects with the highest `score`. Here accumulating into a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and then spreading the iterator returned by `Map.values()` as the result.

```js
const input = [{ score: 99, group: '1' }, { score: 90, group: '2' }, { score: '10', group: '1' }, { score: '10', group: '2' },];

const reduced = input.reduce(
  (a, o) =>
    !a.has(o.group) || o.score > a.get(o.group)?.score
      ? a.set(o.group, { ...o })
      : a,
  new Map()
);

const result = [...reduced.values()];

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

For fun, here is another version:

```js
const data = [
    {"score": 99, "group":"1"},
    {"score": 90, "group":"2"},
    {"score": 10, "group":"1"},
    {"score": 10, "group":"2"},
]

const maxByGroup = {}
for(const entry of data){
  const max = maxByGroup[entry.group]
  maxByGroup[entry.group] = max && max.score >= entry.score ? max : entry
}
const result = Object.values(maxByGroup)

console.log(result)
```

Probably the simplest way to do it, arguably the easiest to read, happens to be the fastest, too